# The same object but have different content(Objective - C)

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a method like:

```
+ (PlayListModel *)transferToPlayListModelWithModel:(HomeLooperInfoDataResponseModel *)model{

    PlayListModel * listModel = [PlayListModel new];

    listModel.isDaily = NO;
    listModel.idField = model.idField;
    listModel.title = model.title;
    listModel.url = model.url;
    listModel.type = model.type;
    listModel.pictureUrl = model.pictureUrlBig;

    listModel.price = model.price;
    listModel.discount_price = model.discount_price;
    listModel.live_count = model.live_count;
    listModel.webViewIntroURL = model.live_url;

    listModel.isCost = model.isCost;
    listModel.is_live = model.is_live;
    listModel.live_end_time = model.live_end_time;
    listModel.live_start_time = model.live_start_time;
    listModel.is_recording = model.is_recording;

    return listModel;

}
```

quite simple , and I invoke it here:

```
PlayListModel *model = [PlayListModel transferToPlayListModelWithModel:currentModel];
NSLog(@"%@",model);
```

and than , it shows me the same object `model` has the different content :
[image]
I want the property isDaily to be No but it return a yes which confused me. I did write `listModel.isDaily = NO` . have no idea where goes wrong.

p.s. this is my descriptionMethod:

```
- (NSString *)description{
    unsigned int count;
    const char *clasName = object_getClassName(self);
    NSMutableString *string = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"<%s: %p>:[ \n",clasName, self];
    Class clas = NSClassFromString([NSString stringWithCString:clasName encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);
    Ivar *ivars = class_copyIvarList(clas, &count);
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        @autoreleasepool {
            Ivar ivar = ivars[i];
            const char *name = ivar_getName(ivar);

            NSString *type = [NSString stringWithCString:ivar_getTypeEncoding(ivar) encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
            NSString *key = [NSString stringWithCString:name encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
            id value = [self valueForKey:key];

            if ([type isEqualToString:@"B"]) {
                value = (value == 0 ? @"NO" : @"YES");
            }
            [string appendFormat:@"\t%@: %@\n",[self delLine:key], value];
        }
    }
    [string appendFormat:@"]"];
    return string;
}
```

Comment: The output in the lower-right of your screenshot seems to be from `NSLog(@"%@", model)` in the code above. That relies on your class implementing the `-description` method. It could be building an inaccurate description string. You'll need to show the implementation of that method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with these lines of your `-description` method:

```
        id value = [self valueForKey:key];

        if ([type isEqualToString:@"B"]) {
            value = (value == 0 ? @"NO" : @"YES");
        }
```

`value` will never equal 0. For a boolean property, it will be an `NSNumber` object that *wraps* the scalar value of the property. Key-Value Coding always deals with objects, never scalars directly.

You can fix it by changing the code to:

```
        id value = [self valueForKey:key];

        if ([type isEqualToString:@"B"]) {
            value = [value boolValue] ? @"YES" : @"NO";
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

The output in the lower-left is the correct value. 
Try this  `NSLog(@"%@", model.isDaily)`  to see the result.

The output in the lower-right is based on the method `-(void)description`  which is implemented in current class  or parent class, maybe in this method you change the property `isDaily` ;